# Call back interfaces in Java

Tags: java, android, callback

So I'm pretty new to Java and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this concept.

I got it working by doing this:

[image]

What I don't understand is that in my WorkerClass I have a constructor that takes as a parameter a type of CallBackInterface.

In my Main Activity class I make a instance of my WorkerClass, by passing the current instance of Main Activity..why does it work? Shouldn't it give me an error because the constructor from WorkerClass requires a different parameter?

Sorry if this sounds dumb, but I wanna understand why it works, and not just remember that it works like this so I will just use it in the future.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Code is text.

Comment: What would be different about the parameter that it requires? I think perhaps the concept you're not understanding is what a Java interface is.

Comment: Read more about interfaces in Java :)

Answer (score 2):

Your activity implements CallBackInterface, so you are not passing a main activity instance into the constructor, but rather instance of CallbackInterface implementation.

If you remove this implementation you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, the "this" keyword got me confused. Another question though: if i have numerous interfaces implemented in a class, and i make instance of several worker classes that have as parameter one of these interfaces, will java know to pass the correct one?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself first? :) The answer is yes though, as long as the object you pass into the constructor implements a needed interface.

Answer (score 0):

> why does it work?

it works because instead of thinking:

***WorkerClass** needs an interface in the constructor*

you can(must) think as

*WorkerClass needs "something" that can do a **callback** in the constructor*.

**MainActivity** implements that **CallbackInterface** so **this** (the actually instance of the main Activity) is holding that contract and can be pass as argument in the constructor.